# Listing from multiple tables in grocery crud

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I just started exploring grocery crud.
I want list the values from multiple tables linked.
As per their guide/tutorials I tried to figure out the solution, but couldn;t able to find solution.
Expected query and solution is on this link
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c5faf/3

```
$crud = $this->generate_crud('admin_users_groups');
$crud->where('group_id','3');
$crud->columns('user_id','DistID');
$crud->display_as('user_id','user');
$crud->set_relation('id', 'dist_info', 'ref_idkey');
//$crud->set_relation_n_n('groups', 'users_groups','groups','user_id','group_id','description');
//$crud->set_relation('user_id', 'admin_users', '{username} - {first_name}{last_name}');
//$crud->set_relation_n_n('DistID', 'admin_users','dist_info','id','id','ref_idkey');
//$crud->set_relation('user_id', 'admin_users', 'email');    
//$crud->set_relation_n_n('id', 'admin_users_groups', 'admin_users', 'id','dist_id', 'name');
//$crud->set_relation_n_n('groups1', 'admin_users_groups', 'admin_groups','user_id', 'group_id', 'name');`
```

Can any one help me to reach to desired solution?

Answer (score 0):

You're just missing some columns in your table. But the real trick is you basically want to display the id column twice, first to show the id and then in the set_relation call, but you can't do that as obviously the library won't know which one is supposed to go where. You have two choices, create a custom model to allow a join of the two tables or use a callback to manually go get the data you need. The second choice should be much easier:

```
$crud = $this->generate_crud('admin_users_groups');
$crud->where('group_id','3');
$crud->columns('id, 'group_id, 'user_id','DistID')
$crud->display_as('user_id','user');
$crud->callback_column('DistID', array($this, 'callback_distID');
...
}

public function callback_distID($value, $row) {
    //Load your model for the 'dist_info'
    $this->load->model('Dist_info_model);
    $dist = $this->Dist_info_model->get_dist_info($row->id);
    return $dist['ref_idkey'];
```

Then in your model:

```
public function get_dist_info($id) {
    return $this->db->getwhere('Dist_info', array('recid'=>$id))->row_array;
```

Comment: So for each distID it will call single query. For 100 rows ...100 queries. Isn't there any better way or via changing the table structure or something ?

Comment: Yes, it would actually simplify things a lot if you just add a column to the admin_users_groups table that simply duplicates the id column. So if this new column was called 'ref_id' then the only lines you would have to change from your original code would be `$crud->columns('id, 'group_id, 'user_id','ref_id');` and `$crud->set_relation('ref_id', 'dist_info', 'ref_idkey');`

Comment: If for whatever reason then you decide you'd rather not change the table structure you're limited to the answer I posted above or using a custom model (The creator of the library posted the code you'd need here: http://www.grocerycrud.com/forums/topic/264-join-tables/#entry1018